# Networkonmainthread exception while executing httprequest in a bound service from another service via aidl

Tags: android, exception, android-service, aidl, networkonmainthread

I have a service which binds another service via aidl.The bound service executes a httprequest and returns a response when the method is invoked from callign service via aidl.
I am getting Networkonmainthread exception while doing this.

Usage of Asynctask failed here for webservice query.Any help is appreciated :)