# Doing networking in Android from AsyncTask gives NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

I am trying to code a simple chat app for Android so I have a chat server and I am trying to connect to it. So in the main class I have

```
final EditText etHost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry1);
final EditText etPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry2);
final EditText messageBoard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText etSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

soEd = new SocketAndEditText(etHost, etPort, messageBoard, etSend);
SetNetworking net = new SetNetworking();
SocketAndEditText net.execute(soEd);
final Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Messager mes = new Messager();
                mes.execute(soEd);
            }
        });
```

`SocketAndEditText` is a class where I simply keep the socket and four `EditText` components. The idea is that `SetNetworking` will establish the network connection and `Messager` will be sending messages. Both classes implement `AsyncTask`:

```
public class SetNetworking extends AsyncTask<SocketAndEditText, Void, Void> {
...

public class Messager extends AsyncTask<SocketAndEditText, Void, Void> {
...
```

But strangely in `onPostExecute(Void result)` in `Messager` when I try to do even a quite simple thing as

```
try {
    InetAddress address1 = InetAddress.getByName("130.237.161.23");
    boolean reachable = address1.isReachable(4456);
    messageBoard.setText("Is host reachable?" + reachable);
} catch (Exception e) {
    messageBoard.setText("Test not working! " + e.toString());
}
```

I get this:

> Test not working! android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Why since it is in the AsyncTask and not in the main thread?

Comment: onPostExecute is done on main thread ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do network I/O in `onPostExecute` of an `AsyncTask`, since that method runs on the UI thread. You need to do all network activity in `doInBackground`.

Comment: Interesting! I guess this could help me solving http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622101/networkonmainthread-exception-while-executing-httprequest-in-a-bound-service-fro/10037830#10037830

Comment: That solved the problem but I have another one now: it returns false (i.e.) the address is not reachable and when I run the same code `InetAddress address1 = InetAddress.getByName("130.237.161.23"); boolean reachable = address1.isReachable(4456);` the result is true. In the manifest I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` What might be the cause?

Comment: @RegedUser00x - I don't understand--what is returning false and what is returning true? It looks like the same code. Perhaps you should start a separate question showing the relevant code.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575747/android-app-fails-to-get-access-to-the-network

Answer (score 0):

Your onPostExecute() of Messager class is done on the Main thread. You are also doing network IO with

> InetAddress.getByName("130.237.161.23");